# Problem when receiving focus on a list (Android)

Tags: android

I have the following XML layout for a ListActivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

```
 <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text="No Contacts" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that if I have focus on any of the header `ImageButton`s then when pressing down with the dpad the list **get focus on its 7th row** (depending on row height), **and not on the first row**. I've seen the same behavior on Fring application, under Contacts.

I tried by listening for the OnKey event for the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN` and triggering a implicit focus on the first item of the list, but I don't know how to do it either.

Do you have any idea on how to focus the first row of the List when getting the focus with a  KeyEvent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, when using minSdkVersion=3 the behavior is as described in this question. When using minSdkVersion=4 or higher it will work as expected. Don't know why though.